# Android - add menu item to Android's built-in apps?

Tags: android

I'd like to add a menu option to the Android camera app. Is this possible to do using the current SDK?

Thanks.

**Edit :** Ok I know I need to add an intent-filter tag in my activity. But I don't know what I should put in the mime type. I want to be able to process the live camera previews if the user selects the menu option. So what do I put into the type tag of the intent-filter?
Also I suppose I won't be using ALTERNATIVE or SELECTED-ALTERNATIVE for the category as I want to deal with the whole intent?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the built-in Android applications do not add third-party options to their menus.

Answer (score 5):

The closest you can get is to add an option to the 'Share' menu of the built-in camera application. The built-in e-mail app uses the following intent-filter to do this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
  <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

(Note the mime-type is specific to image files.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the build in applications are mostly open source.
Maybe you should go to the source code and compile your camera with the added menu buttons yourself?