# How to add own application to SMS context menu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

Currently if I long-tap on the SMS message, there is a context menu. One of the item there is Send (or Share - not sure about exact name in English). Then here I see applications like Add To Pocket, Add to Springpad, Bluetooth, Gmail, Skype etc. How can I add own application there? What kind of SMS data I will be able to get (something besides SMS text)?

Comment: I came across [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/vT5cKHxm3DU) but I feel like it might be oudated considering Pocket and Springpad are in there. I will update you if I find anything else, though.

Comment: [This is what CommonsWare also says, but there may be some tinkering you can do with Intent filters.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286434/android-add-menu-item-to-androids-built-in-apps)